# Size limit error while creating layers in aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to create a layer in lambda by adding my zipped python folder into s3 and then using the zipped file's s3 link to create layer in lambda.
But its showing me error which says unzipped file size must be smaller than 250 Mb.
The packages that I needed are pandas, pyqb, urllib3, xlsxwriter, and awswrangler.
awswrangler have many dependencies due to which zipped file will have at least 78 Mb and the unzipped file size is going to cross 250 Mb.
How to solve this limitation. Please suggest me some workaround.

I have followed [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/add-external-python-libraries-aws-lambda-using-layers-gabe-olokun/)  article for installing and uploading the zipped file to s3 and then creating layer.
[image]

Comment: You can use lambda container instead. It has 10GB limit size instead of 250MB.

Comment: @Marcin I have used amazon cloudshell in installing the packages and then uploading them to s3. Is the steps in using container different ?

Comment: Yes, with containers, you're essentially creating a docker image and pushing that to ecr instead of the current approach of pushing code to S3